# Compact sets for this topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X:=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the Cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ by itself $\mathbb{N}$-times, and for each integer $n\geq 1$ define the semi-norm

$$
\rho_{n}(x):=\max\{|x_{i}|:i=1,\ldots, n\}
$$

for each $x:=(x_{k})_{k\geq 1}\in X $. We consider $X$ endowed the topology generated the this family of semi-norms.

Assume $K\subset X$ is compact. It is true that there exist $M>0$ such that, for each $x\in K$, $|x_{i}|\leq M$ for all $i\geq 1$?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $K_n=\{0,n\}$, and let $K=\prod_{n\ge 1}K_n$; $K$ is a product of compact spaces, so it is a compact subspace of $X$, but $\langle 1,2,3,\ldots\rangle\in K$. (In fact $K$ is a Cantor set.)

Comment: Thanks. But, your example is compact for the product topology, my question is related to the topology generated by the indicated family of seminorms. I edit the question

Comment: @user123043: It’s the same topology.

Answer (score 2):

No, define $C_n = [-n,n] \subseteq \Bbb R$. Then $K=\prod_n I_n$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem but $\forall n: \exists x \in K: \rho_n(x) \ge n$, so we cannot bound the seminorms.

Comment: Thanks. But, your example is compact for the product topology, my question is related to the topology generated by the indicated family of seminorms. I edit the question.

Comment: @user123043 that’s the same topology!